# Calling FaceBook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

Recently received advanced access to Page Public Metadata but receiving error that we don't access to  endpoint when searching pages with Graph API. The following is the error received:

> "{    "error": {
> "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access'
> feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages,
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS
> and
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access
> for details.",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 10,
> "fbtrace_id": "AZ2mHh8hOni4sfiVCZ9yk6w"    } }"

Here is a screenshot of the permissions granted for Page Public Metadata Access

[image: Permissions and features]

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using wrong Token - you need to use App token, but not User or Page tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. The issue was that the "App Mode" was set to Development rather than Live in FB. After switching, requests were allowed.